# Is it possible to generate an integer by using Math.random()*80 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, random

I know even if it can, the probability would be really small but is it theoretically possible?

Comment: `Math.random() * 80 | 0`

Comment: While the answer of [Rivenfall](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32349055/1960455) is most likely what you are looking for, it should be noted that all numbers in JS are `double` [MDN: Number type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type): `[...]According to the ECMAScript standard, there is only one number type: the double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value (number between -(253 -1) and 253 -1). There is no specific type for integers.[...]`.

Comment: I think the question referred to the production of a mathematical integer (non-fractional), not an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the ECMAScript standard, there is only one number type: the double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754 value (number between -(253 -1) and 253 -1). There is no specific type for integers.

So, are there any IEEE 754 numbers that become integer when multiplied by 80?

80 = 2*2*2*2*5. Since the value is stored using binary fractions, the numbers n/16, where n is in the range [1-15] can all be represented exactly. They also become an integer when multiplied by 80.

So there are at least 15 different values that will result in an integer when multiplied by 80.

Can the random number generator actually produce any of these values? I cannot say. That would depend on the javascript implementation.

Answer (score 0):

... ? Yes :

You want an integer between  0 and 80 ?

`var my_integer = parseInt (""+ 80 * Math.random());`

**EDIT** You can also round it (`floor`,`ceil`) down & up:

Floor does, e.g. : 76,8=>76

`var my_integer = Math.floor( parseInt (""+ 80 * Math.floor()));`

Ceil does, e.g. : 76,8=>77

`var my_integer = Math.ceil(parseInt (""+ 80 * Math.ceil()));`

Answer (score -1):

Yes it's possible. From node console:

```
> for(var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
...   var rn = Math.random() * 80
...   if(rn == Math.round(rn)) {
.....     console.log('success')
.....     break
.....   }
... }
success
undefined
>
```